# Controller not creating association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested-attributes

I've got two models, Users and Organizations, which have a has_many relationship using an assignments table. I have a nested resource form when the user is created, which creates an associated organization just fine. However, when creating an organization, it doesn't associate it with the user.

Here's my relevant Organizations controller code:

```
  def new
    @organization = current_user.organizations.build
  end

  def create
    @organization = current_user.organizations.build(params[:organization])
    @organization.save
  end
```

And my models:

Organizations Assignments

```
class OrganizationAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization

  attr_accessible :user_id, :organization_id
end
```

Organizations:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :subdomain, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  has_many :organization_assignments
  has_many :people
  has_many :users, :through => :organization_assignments

  attr_accessible :name, :subdomain
end
```

Users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :organization_assignments
  has_many :organizations, :through => :organization_assignments

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :organizations_attributes
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

end
```

form view:

```
= form_for @organization, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  - @organization.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    .alert.alert-error
      %h3
        = pluralize(@organization.errors.count, 'error')
        prohibited this user from being saved:
      %ul
        %li
          = msg

  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

  = f.label :subdomain
  = f.text_field :subdomain

  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), organizations_path, :class => 'btn'
```

I'm able to associate the organizations fine after the fact in the console, so I'm pretty sure the relationships are set up correctly in the model. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean creating straight organization? You mean creating organization directly without associating user like `Organization.create!`

Comment: Share you view template as well

Comment: @Arun Sorry, I was unclear. I'm trying to create an organization that is associated with the current user, but not while creating a user.

Comment: @AmitPatel here's the view code:
`
= form_for @organization, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  - @organization.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
    .alert.alert-error
      %h3
        = pluralize(@organization.errors.count, 'error')
        prohibited this user from being saved:
      %ul
        %li
          = msg

  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name

  = f.label :subdomain
  = f.text_field :subdomain

  .form-actions
    = f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")), organizations_path, :class => 'btn'`